# Cloudformation LaunchTemplate referencing IamInstanceProfile fails to create

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I am trying to create a *LaunchTemplate*, which references an *IamInstanceProfile*, in my Cloudformation stack. Here is the code- i have omitted the irrelevant parts:

```
...
            Resources:
              ServerLaunchTemplate:
                Type: 'AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate'
                Properties:
                  LaunchTemplateData:
                    InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
                    SecurityGroups:
                      - !Ref SecGroup
                    IamInstanceProfile: !Ref ServerProfile
                    UserData:
        ...
              ServerProfile:
                Type: 'AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile'
                Properties:
                  Path: /
                  Roles:
                    - !Ref ServerRole
...
```

The *ServerProfile* gets created successfully. However when the stack creation process reaches the step of creating the *ServerLaunchTemplate*, it fails with the error:

```
Property validation failure: [Value of property {/LaunchTemplateData/IamInstanceProfile} does not match type {Object}]
```

If i omit the reference to the *IamInstanceProfile*, the *LaunchTemplate* get created successfully.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-launchtemplate-launchtemplatedata.html#cfn-ec2-launchtemplate-launchtemplatedata-iaminstanceprofile) and some examples this should work... Based on the error i understand, that the *InstanceType* field of the *LaunchTemplate* needs to reference an object, but "*!Ref InstanceType*" returns the resource id.

How can i fix this? How could i retrieve the object, that is presumably required by the "*/LaunchTemplateData/IamInstanceProfile*" field?

Thank you

Comment: A workaround would be to attach the IamInstanceProfile to the AWS::EC2:Instance you are tried to create. If you re initiating multiple,  the disadvantage is it will of course lead to copy-and-pasting.

Answer (score 23):

Easy to miss in the docs: IamInstanceProfile requires an IamInstanceProfile Cloudformation object with the Arn of the referenced IamInstanceProfile being a property of it.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-launchtemplate-launchtemplatedata.html#cfn-ec2-launchtemplate-launchtemplatedata-iaminstanceprofile and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-launchtemplate-iaminstanceprofile.html.

This should work:

```
  PortalLaunchTemplate:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate'
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateName: !Sub ${InstanceName}-launch-template
      LaunchTemplateData:
        ImageId: !Ref AmiId
        ...
        IamInstanceProfile:
          Arn: !GetAtt InstanceProfile.Arn
```

Comment: Also, ensure you're not using a list for the property - I was getting this error because I had `- Arn: ...` which should have been just `Arn: ...`

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:

```
"IamInstanceProfile":{ "Arn": 

{
"Fn::Sub":"arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:instanceprofile/${name_of_Instance_profile}"

}
```

Presumably because it requires the "Arn" value as a string.